# Snap functionality in iOS

Tags: objective-c

I have a parent UIView which contains 3 subviews, here i have one UIButton to take snap of the whole view. i have done this using

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(320,480));
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

UIImage *screenShot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext(); 

[self.view.layer renderInContext:context];
```

here i need to capture only the 1st subview which name is subview1. how can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

`Capture` `SubView` like this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(subview1.size);
[subview1.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *screenShot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```